# HighCharts and Handlebars

Tags: jquery, highcharts, handlebars.js

Is it possible to inject a Highcharts chart into a Handlebars template during compilation? I can't seem to get the element with which to inject the chart. I usually can do something like `$('#value-graph').highcharts(options);` but here it doesn't seem to work. Has anyone had success with this or is it not possible in handlebars?

```js
var data = {
  name: 'This',
  address: '1141 Rd'
};
var source = $('#company-template').html(); // not sure if this is the selector name
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var content = template(data);
Handlebars.registerHelper('drawGraph', function() {
  var options = {
    chart: {
      height: 160
    },
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    }
  };

  options.xAxis.categories = ["Nov '13", "Dec '13"];
  options.series = [{
    data: [100, 50];
  }];

  $('#value-graph').highcharts(options);
});
```

```html
script#company-template(type='text/x-handlebars-template').
  <section class="header">
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
    <div class="address">{{address}}</div>
  </section>
  <section class="details">
    <div class="graph" id="value-graph">{{drawGraph}}</div>
  </section>
```

Comment: $('#value-graph').highcharts(options), it won't work value-graph is not part of the DOM object

Comment: [Looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046069/including-existing-dom-element-with-handlebars) template doesn't have information where it's generated, and helper needs to return a string. Highcharts requires some DOM element where needs to be created. Probably some workaround with shadow DOM would be enough, or generate chart outside the template (which doesn't sound like a real solution..).

Comment: @hotshotiguana, Were you able to use highchart or any js library in handlebars?